# Convert a string to number in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this

```
const ArrayOfObject = [
{x: "1622078100000", y: 1},
{x: "1622010000000", y: 1},
{x: "1622009940000", y: 6},
{x: "1622009880000", y: 4},
{x: "1622009820000", y: 2},
{x: "1622073600000", y: 1}
]
```

I want something like this

const ArrayOfObject = [

```
{x: 1622078100000, y: 1},
{x: 1622010000000, y: 1},
{x: 1622009940000, y: 6},
{x: 1622009880000, y: 4},
{x: 1622009820000, y: 2},
{x: 1622073600000, y: 1}
]
```

parse the x prop from string to number. How to accomplish this in Javascript ES6 or ES5?

Comment: Use parseInt (or parseFloat) `var num = parseInt(string);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the + unary operator to convert a string to a number, like so:

```
const newArr = [];
ArrayOfObject.forEach(obj => newArr.push({x: +obj.x, y: obj.y}));
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus

Answer (score 2):

There is no special function to do this. You literally have to map over them.
Better instead to leave them as is, and only do it when needed

```js
const ArrayOfObject = [
{x: "1622078100000", y: 1},
{x: "1622010000000", y: 1},
{x: "1622009940000", y: 6},
{x: "1622009880000", y: 4},
{x: "1622009820000", y: 2},
{x: "1622073600000", y: 1}
]

const ArrayOfObjectUpdated = ArrayOfObject.map(item => ({...item, x: Number(item.x)}))
```

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate it